# C# Parallel.For and Oracle database access - memory exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I am working on some code that I would like to access an Oracle database inside of a `Parallel.For` loop. The loop will run for several minutes, and then result in the error:

> "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt."

There is no inner exception. Inside my `Parallel.For` loop, I am creating an opening the database connection as local objects. My code looks like this:

```
static void CheckSinglePath(Path p)
{    
     string sqlBase = "select * from table where hour = #HOUR#";
     Parallel.For (1, 24, i =>
     {        
            DBManager localdbm = new DBManager();                
            string sql = sqlBase;
            sql = sql.Replace("#HOUR#", i.ToString());
            OracleDataReader reader = db.GetData(sql);
            if (reader.Read())
            {
               //do some stuff
            }
            reader.Close();
     });
}

class DBManager
{
    OracleConnection conn;
    OracleCommand cmd;
    public DBManager()
    {
        string connStr = "blahblahblah;Connection Timeout=600;";
        conn = new OracleConnection(connStr);            
        conn.Open();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    }

    public OracleDataReader GetData(string sql)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();//EXCEPTION HERE!
    }        
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I create 24 parallel Oracle connections to process the data? I'm guessing there is some sort of race condition or memory leak that is going on here which I don't fully understand because it seems to be coming from inside the `OracleConnection` object. Is the database connection not threadsafe? I tried changing the connection string to use a connection pool and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory problems is **always** caused by wrong resources usage. You do not properly release your connections after the loop exit.

You need to implement [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface and after that you need rewrite your code in such manner with [`using` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
// dispose the connection after command finished
using (var localdbm = new DBManager())
{            
    var sql = sqlBase;
    sql = sql.Replace("#HOUR#", i.ToString());
    using (var reader = db.GetData(sql))
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
           //do some stuff
        }
        // no need to close reader
        // as it's being disposed inside using directive
    }
}
```

Comment: How would not disposing a resource earlier cause access of invalid memory? If anything not having dispose would hide such a bug since the memory would keep valid for longer.

Comment: @Voo OP meets the memory error **after some**, so unmanaged resources simply lead him to memory corruption

Comment: How would not freeing memory ever lead to accessing freed memory? If you don't dispose unmanaged resources you'll run out of resources, not get access errors (except if we run out of memory and the unmanaged code doesn't check the return value of malloc and co)

Comment: Memory is **not** freed in this case, thats the problem. Only **managed** resources are freed, **non-managed** remain in memory. After some time there is basically no space to store a new connection.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the new code this morning and it's been running for a couple hours with no exceptions.  Thanks!!